# How to predict next X values in my model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, predict

I have this program that is used to predict outflow of a reservoir and I cannot seem to get it to predict the next day worth of data. The data is in 30 minute increments and would expect 48 points of data to represent the next 24 hours. Is there something I am doing incorrect or have missed?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout

# Prepare data
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"])

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data["Outlet"].values.reshape(-1, 1))

prediction_days = 30

x_train, y_train = [], []

for x in range(prediction_days, len(scaled_data)):
    x_train.append(scaled_data[x-prediction_days:x, 0])
    y_train.append(scaled_data[x, 0])

x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(x_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))

# Create neural network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=25)

# Test the model
test_start = dt.datetime(2022, 1, 1)
test_end = dt.datetime.now()
actual_outlet = data[(data['Date'] >= test_start) & (data['Date'] <= test_end)]['Outlet']
total_dataset = pd.concat((data['Outlet'], actual_outlet), axis=0)

model_inputs = total_dataset[len(total_dataset) - len(actual_outlet) - prediction_days:].values
model_inputs = model_inputs.reshape(-1, 1)
model_inputs = scaler.transform(model_inputs)

x_test = []

for x in range(prediction_days, len(model_inputs)):
    x_test.append(model_inputs[x-prediction_days:x, 0])

x_test = np.array(x_test)
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))

prediction_outlet = model.predict(x_test)
prediction_outlet = scaler.inverse_transform(prediction_outlet)
print(len(prediction_outlet))
```

The length of my `prediction_outlet` comes to 1056. Have I missed some steps?

Comment: Is there any way you can share a bit of sample data?

Comment: @ahmethamzaemra  [See JS Fiddle with data](https://jsfiddle.net/n5woLq64/). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your test data has 22 days of data since you are taking the slice from `test_start` to today. since you have 48 data points for each day it adds up to 1056 data points to predict. So you are making the right length of predictions. On the other hand, since you don't have it ordered some of the dates are mixed up. In one instance you have half of the data points from Feb-02 and the rest from Jan-13 which will be very confusing for the network. You might want to order them and make sure you don't take missing dates in your slices.

Comment: I appreciate that note, thank you for that. Additional question to follow up on for you if you could. I am unable to print out 48 predicted values from the above code. Could you point me in the direction to fix that. Currently just prints one value.